# split a zone file in multiple locations (for statis entries and ddns updates)

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, bind, ddns

Im'm trying to have dhcp update my bind9 zone file with leases of clients, but, as I understand it /etc/bind/ is not writable by bind - should be just for reading static zone files. But /var/lib/bind is. So my zone files should go into the latter.
Except I have records that I think should be static, like static leases or MX records...
Could I place an $INCLUDE statement in /etc/bind/myzone.db and 192.168.0.in-addr.arpa.db pointing to /var/lib/bind/myzone.db and /var/lib/bind/192.168.0.in-addr.arpa.db respectively?
And how would bind then be able to know that it should update the file in /var and not the one in /etc?